# android: how add section footer to a list

Tags: android, listview, footer

I'm using SeperatedListAdapter available here: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

but I want to create a list with footer for each section. i don't know how should i do this.
any other solution to create a section-List with footer for each section will be helpful.

edited:

now i change the adapter as bellow:

```
footers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.footer_layout);
    public int getCount() {  
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header  
        int total = 0;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getCount() + 2;  
        return total;  
    }  


//@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    int sectionnum = 0;  
    for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 2;  

        // check if position inside this section  
        if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);  
        if(position < size-1) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);
        if(position == size -1)  return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent); 

        // otherwise jump into next section  
        position -= size;  
        sectionnum++;  
    }  
    return null;  
}
```

but i get index exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new layout that is returned in getView (in your adapter) as the last position in each section. (instead of first in each section)

I believe that is the similar to the solution that the SeperatedListAdapter uses.

Comment: hi oscar. thanx for your answer. but could you plz explain that more. I'm beginner in android...

Comment: What do you want? Both sections and footers?

Comment: a simple solution works like this.

- In your ListView, add your adapter (class that extends BaseAdapter)
- The adapter should contain data about the data structure, possibly a list of sections, with their data. 
- in getCount of the adapter, return the amount of items in the list (e.g if you have 3 sections with 2 items each and a section and a footer, you should return 3 * (2 items + 1 header + 1 footer) = 12.
- in getView of the adapter, figure out what you should return, an item, header or footer.

Comment: thanks alot.  but still i have a problem. i did anything you said. but i have problem when i want to return view of the footer in getView function. when program is executed it gets index Exception. maybe it is because of this line :(if(position == size -1)  return footers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);). but when i use headers instead "footers" in above statement, it works fine

Comment: i has fixed the problem. it was just because i has forgot to initial the footer. thank you oscar :)

Comment: No problem! I believe this is more complicated than it has to be... but if it works :)

BTW, please mark this as solved